# Order results by the length of varchar/nvarchar column value in EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

How can I order the results set by the **length** of column value in EF Core?

One of the entity properties is `barcode`, which I need to bring entities with shorter barcodes on top of the list while searching the value likeliness not exact match.

In SQL :

```
Select * 
From dbo.Barcodes 
Where BarcodeValue Like '%221%'
Order By Len(BarcodeValue) Asc
```

How to do this in EF Core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dbo.Barcodes.Where(x => x.BarcodeValue.Contains("221")).OrderBy(x=> x.BarcodeValue.Length)
```